# Use Oracle Wallet To Store Symmetric Keys

Tags: oracle, plsql, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, oracle-wallet

Can I use Oracle Wallet to store and retrieve symmetric keys?

For example to use them by **DBMS_CRYPTO** to data encryption/decryption.

thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like it (I just looked into it because I was unaware of the existence of these kind of wallets). I see some support for private keys (for X.509 certificates) and passwords, but that's it. An ugly way is to encode a key encoded as byte array as a password and retrieve it again. I would call that an ugly hack though - better use another key store.